# boost::filesystem version issues

Tags: boost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, I've been building ROS on Fedora 15, and there are a few persistent issues that keep cropping up every time the ROS source code is updated.

The most annoying issue is concerning the version of the Boost libraries used in the code. A bit of googling brought me [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/996/boost-symbols-not-found) which made me realize that this was an issue with the changeover from boost::filesystem from v2 to v3, and so I had to add a #define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 2 to all files including a `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>`. To find these files, I used

```
find . | xargs grep 'boost/filesystem.hpp' -sl
```

this gave me about 9 files which I modified, and ran the script again.

Do I report this as an issue?

Additionally, unlike ubuntu all the packages/stacks are not rosmake'd on install. For example, for image_view, I need to rosmake image_views and the plugins and opencv2 (For which I had to do the same Boost thing to boost_fs_wrapper.cpp)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10462/boost::filesystem-version-issues/) by [ICodeRaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/793/icoderaven/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2011-07-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-07-18**:
Related post http://answers.ros.org/question/996/boost-symbols-not-found?answer=1689#1689

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If there's a specific package broken please file tickets for the specific package.  The transition from boost filesystem 2 -> 3 is going to be generally painful and each usage will likely have to have ifdef logic for a while.

The rosmake is true on any system where you are installing from source.  You need to compile all the packages you expect to use.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4